# sklearn.svm.SVC - UserWarning: indptr array has non-integer dtype (float64)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting this warning for using `sklearn.svm.SVC` (version 0.16.1),

```
logger.info('the shape of tf_feature is : (%d, %d)', 
  features.tf_feature.shape[0],features.tf_feature.shape[1])
## output: the shape of tf_feature is : (11269, 53975)

svc = svm.SVC(C = 0.05)
## tf_feature is a sparse csr matrix
svc.fit(features.tf_feature, features.label) # getting warning here
```

the full warning is

`sr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:119: UserWarning: indptr array has non-integer dtype (float64) % self.indptr.dtype.name)`.

It is strange that if I replace `svm.SVC` by `svm.LinearSVC` it becomes totally fine. Anybody knows what is going on with `svm.SVC`?

Comment: Which version of scipy is installed? Maybe you should update it?

Comment: @Olologin, thanks. scipy was '0.13.3'. After I have installed a most recent git version of scipy, the warning disappeared. But I am getting results from `SVC` which don't make sense at all, and the results from `LinearSVC` are much better.